# AWS showing volume and lsblk showing same volume size but df -H not showing. Are we able to use full AWS volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

AWS showing 100GB volume and lsblk showing same volume size but df -H showing 30GB.
I am curious to know, are my application able to use 100GB or there will be issue after 30GB.

Thank you in advance

**AWS Dashboard:**
[image]

**Command: lsblk**

[image]

**Command: df -H**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu OS. Steps to add volume in /dev/root

1. ssh to ec2 server
2. lsblk
3. df -H
4. sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1
   Note: Between xvda and 1 have space
5. lsblk
6. sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1
   Note: No space between xvda and 1
7. df -H